# Saving a Hashtable using Mongo & the Play framework?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, hashtable

I've got a model defined like the following...

```
@MongoEntity
public class Ent extends MongoModel{
   public Hashtable<Integer, CustomType> fil;
   public int ID;

   public Ent(){
     fil = new Hashtable<Integer, CustomType>();
   }
}
```

`CustomType` is a datatype I've created which basically holds a list of items (among other things). At some point in my web application I update the hashtable from a controller and then read back the size of the item I just updated. Like the following...

```
public static void addToHash(CustomType type, int ID, int key){

   //First I add an element to the list I'm storing in custom type.
   Ent ent = Ent.find("byID",ID).first();
   CustomType element = user.fil.get(key);
   if(element == null) element = new CustomType();

   element.add(type);
   ent.save();

   //Next I reset the variables and read back the value I just stored..
   ent = null;
   ent = User.find("byID",ID).first();
   element = ent.fil.get(ID);
       System.out.println("SIZE = " + element.size()); //null pointer here
}
```

As you can see by my above example I add the element, save the model and then attempt to read back what I have just added and it has not been saved. The above model `Ent` is a minimal version of the entire Model I'm actually using. All other values in the model including `List`'s, `String`'s, `Integer`'s etc. update correctly when they're updated but this `Hashtable` I'm storing isn't. Why would this be happening and how could I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post on the play framework forum for better help..
Alternatives for a mongodb framework are morphia and springdata which have good documentation.
Not sure how Play maps a hash table to a document value, but it seems it cannot update just the hash table using a mongo operator.
You should be able to mark the whole document for update which would work but slower.